# weird page when using media query

Tags: css, mobile, web, media-queries

I'm doing a page it use media query:

```
@media
only screen and (max-width: 320px){}
```

If the page width size <= 320px (we call it small page), it will load the css inside media query. 
But I meet a problem, if I open a tab1 in Chrome, and resize the browser width less than 320px, the mobile style page will show, but then I open a new page in new tab2, then maximize this tab, some while later(5 minutes), go back to tab1, it still load the mobile style. If I go back immediately, the tab1 will show the correct css style.
Please see the screeshot.[image: normal account summary page][image: small page load the media query style][image: Weird page, if maximize another tab, some while later, go back to account summary page, it will be like this, the expect result is showing the normal page]

Picture 1 is the normal page
Picture 2 is the small page load the media query style
Picture 3 is the weird page, if maximize another tab, some while later, go back to account summary page, it will be like this, the expect result is showing the normal page

Comment: Does anybody meet the same kind of issue?

Comment: can you provide a live code using sites like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It looks like there's a media query playing up somewhere — need to see code example really.

Comment: Hi @NoorAhmadFeroozi: Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/NYw6E/1 and http://jsfiddle.net/NYw6E/1/embedded/result if resize the windows less than 320px, then open another tab, and maximize the windows, some while later, go back to jsfiddle, you could see it still use the css inside media query. I want it will load the css outside media query.

Comment: @阳光Emi Here, Its refreshing to normal style when maximizing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the opposite.

Maybe should you try :

only screen and (min-width: 320px){}

instead of

only screen and (max-width: 320px){}
.